# Is there an inclusive term for all definable items within a class?

Tags: c#, oop

In a C# class, you can obviously define numerous *objects* that are pretty common across any form of software development.

There are variables...

```
int i;
```

properties...

```
int I { get {return i;} set {i = value;} }
```

methods...

```
public int getI() { return I; }
```

constructors (which could be considered a function, depending on who you ask)...

```
public myClass() { i = -1; }
```

Technically speaking, the variables and the properties are often called "objects".  Likewise, a delegate to the method can be passed around as an object, and is considered to be an object.

What I'm not sure of is if *semantically* we would consider the method an object.  Regarding the delegate/method relationship, the delegate IS NOT the method.  It is a pointer TO the method.  Ergo, I am inclined to not consider the method to be an object.

With that stated, is there a definable, all-inclusive term for all *objects* that can be defined within a C# class (or any OO language) which includes variables, properties, methods, functions, constructors, constants, etc.?

To be clear, I'm not asking for an opinion on this.  I want to know, by textbook/specification definition, what are these items called within C# and OOP?

Comment: You forgot `event`s and nested types...

Comment: "Class members", I suppose.

Comment: @xantos Depending on who  you ask, there is a lot that I'm missing.  I'm not trying to create the full list.  I just want the generalized term for anything that *could* be in the list.

Comment: Objects in .net is something derived from [`object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) (*All classes, structures, enumerations, and delegate*), don't call members so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct name for them is [*members*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113.aspx).

Comment: I am mostly asking for C#.  Curious, is this generally true across OOP? (Within and outside the realm of MS development?)

Comment: I guess so, but every programming language has its own names. I guess *members* is quite a generic term, so it would fit most languages. See the difference for example in *procedure*, *function* and *method*.

Comment: @RLH, all terms in .net is a subset of [oop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) terms. OOP is more generic and abstract. However, when talking to someone you can point him in which context your terms are (because some languages needs more terms or use them in limited meaning, e.g. [traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)), [mixins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin), etc.). Tell him "C# is cool and java suxx" or something like this to make it even more clear ;)

Answer (score 5):

They are called members... And they aren't objects (at least not in the .NET definition).

If you use reflection, all the various `FieldInfo`, `MethodInfo`, `PropertyInfo`, `EventInfo`... subclass `MemberInfo`, and if you do a `typeof(List<int>).GetMembers()` you'll get all the public members. This method will even return nested types (because even `Type` is a `MemberInfo`).

Note that `delegate`s don't exist as a first-level "item" of .NET: they are simply a `class` that subclasses `MulticastDelegate` (and/or perhaps even `Delegate`, but this isn't doable in C#, perhaps directly in IL)

Comment: I won't belabor this question but I think @Sinatr brings up a good point in the question comment above (or at least how I interpret the comment) These devices are called members from where they exist in the classes.  However, as a group, what do we call variables, methods, constructors, etc.  These are coding devices, used to come together as a class.  As a group, what are the called where no relationship exists.  This is probably the only answer but there seems that there should likely be some very high-level definition for everything that we can define/create in OO code.

Comment: @RLH I don't comprehend your comment. The only Sinatr comment is about the fact that they aren't object. I tell the same (*And they aren't objects (at least not in the .NET definition).*). Note that what you call *variable*s are in truth *field*s. Variable are "things" local to a method body.